# What is happening with this hummingbird and how can I help him?

Tags: ornithology

Today I noticed a hummingbird next to my feeder (California) which looks very strange. From my observation it seems that something sticks from its head. This thing is rigid (does not look like a spider web) and bothers the bird (from time to time the bird tries to use a leg to get rid of it).

The bird can fly (slower than other hummingbirds) and it seems like it eats from the feeder (but puts its head deeper into the feeder than other hummingbirds).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**What is this? And more importantly how can I help the bird?**

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You might have better luck at [Pets.SE], since this is essentially a veterinary question. If you do decide to try there (please check their help section for suitability), please either request migration or delete this post before reposting there ([cross-posting is impolite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)). Good luck!

Comment: @tyersome thanks for the reply and sorry if this question is inappropriate here. I was looking at `pets` but thought that it might not be the right place as hummingbirds are unlikely to be pets (agree that this is more a veterinary question). If you think it is better to migrate it there, please migrate it.

Comment: No problem! I've seen a few wild-bird related posts at [Pets.se] , but I'm not active there so I can't guarantee this will work there. I'm not a moderator, so I can't migrate this. If you want to initiate migration, just flag your answer and select "in need of moderator intervention". Enter something like: `Please migrate this to Pets.SE, I think it would fit better there because ...`. Alternatively, you can delete the post from this site and repost it on Pets.SE. ——— It also might be more effective to reach out to a local wild animal rescue organization for advice/help.